# Best way to create a Punnett Square in PHP?

Tags: php, genetics, genetic

I've hunted high and low for some answers to this but can't find anything helpful.

I'm working on a genetics project, and I need to create a script that can generate a punnett square from the genetics passed.

The sort of thing I'll be working with is something like `bbEe x bbEe`, but there could be longer strings like `bbEeWwss x bbeeSS`.

It could then result in something like `bbee`, `bbEe`, `bbEE`

I've had ideas on using arrays to split the alleles and combine them but i feel like that might be quite costly resource wise.

Is there a smart way of achieving what i'm trying to do?

Thanks for any info,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are after a PHP solution, but there is a solution written in javascript that might actually be easier to work with: https://github.com/armatronic/punnett-squares-js

Here's a preview of how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at this. I need a PHP version as I'm working with some database entries that are JSON and will be working with the data in other ways too but this is definitely a start